# Disable Recent Orders Only Customer Account Dashboard

Tags: customer-account

who disable recent orders only customer account dashboard.

And I want to avoid using other modules sidebar. I just want the customer menu are displayed.

thank you

[image]

Comment: you need to remove all the sidebar links except dashboard in customer my account page

Comment: yes all links..

Comment: you need to remove compare sidebar

Answer (score 1):

To remove recent orders in customer dashboard page. Add below code in your local.xml or any layout files.

```
<customer_account_index>
 <!-- Mage_Sales --> 
     <remove name="customer_account_dashboard_top"/>
</customer_account_index>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove recent orders from customer account dashboard page,

```
<customer_account_index>
 <!-- Mage_Sales --> 
     <remove name="customer_account_dashboard_top"/>
</customer_account_index>
```

To remove links from customer account page,

Add the below code in `template/customer/account/navigation.phtml` ,

```
          <?php 
                unset($_links['tags']); /* My Tags */
                unset($_links['OAuth Customer Tokens']); /* My Applications */
                unset($_links['reviews']);  /* Reviews */
                unset($_links['wishlist']); /* Wishlist */
                unset($_links['newsletter']); /* Newsletter */
                unset($_links['orders']); /* My Orders */
                unset($_links['downloadable_products']); /* My Downloadable Products */
                unset($_links['recurring_profiles']); /* Recurring Profiles */
                unset($_links['billing_agreements']); /* Billing Agreements */
            ?>
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/Aproducktion/Magento-Remove-Dashboard-Links) for reference.

Comment: Thank you and, I am sorry, I was wrong expression. Customer panel not to delete links. only links are shown. I made a few attempts. example:    <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/>
        <remove name="left.testimonials"/>

Comment: I uptade question please see image